# Permission for xml file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have an **xml file** in my project .Its working fine in my system but when I published and placed the code in the server I have to give permission manually (Rt click)  `properties` setting to **everyone**.

Is there any other way to set permission via coding?.

Comment: You should be giving permission NOT to everyone; but to the account under which the Application Pool associated with your website is running.

Comment: @Prash I have to make this change in the Xml file. May I know to set this property

Comment: You cannot set any property, especially in your xml file, in order to control the permissions. You should do this manually.